# How to concatenate two values into one

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to concatenate two combo boxes value into 1 column of `GridView` in C#. I am using this code but it not concatenate it..

```
private void linetotal_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.KeyCode==Keys.Enter)
    {
        object[] values = { cbxclassstd.Text,cbxfee.Text,
                             feeamount.Text,disc.Text,linetotal.Text};
        this.dgvvoucher.Rows.Add(values);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`string.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) to concatenate your `Combobox`'s values into one column:

```
this.dgvvoucher.Rows.Add(string.Join("", values));//Or string.Join(",", values)
```

And if you just need to concatenate first two items:

```
this.dgvvoucher.Rows.Add(string.Join("", new[] { values[0] , values[1] }));
```

Comment: can u plz explain it more..how to do that

Comment: @hashirkhan The `string.Join` method, will *concatenates all the elements of a string array, using the specified separator between each element.* Just copy and paste my code, i just added the  `string.Join` to your code.

Comment: i use this code.......this.dgvvoucher.Rows.Add(string.Join("cbxclassstd.text + cbxfee.text", values));

Comment: @hashirkhan Use my code exactly, the first parameter of the `Join` method is separator. Just try my code and see the result!

Comment: i want to concatenate cbxclassstd.text text box value and cbxfee combo box text value into 1 cell name Fee and show 2 values in it in datagrid view

Comment: ur code is concatenating all the values but i want to concatenate first two values only

Comment: @hashirkhan Try this `this.dgvvoucher.Rows.Add(string.Join("", new[] { cbxclassstd.Text, cbxfee.Text }));`

Comment: @hashirkhan Or this `this.dgvvoucher.Rows.Add(string.Join("", new[] { values[0] , values[1] }));`

Comment: ok..now first two values are coming in one column but my values which have to come in other column of grid respectively is not coming..like feeamount.text which have to come in separate column and other values also come into separate column is not working

Comment: i use this to get remaining field values but not working..

Comment: this.dgvvoucher.Rows.Add(string.Join("-", new[] { values[0], values[1] }),values);

Comment: plz help me to fix this....how can i specify other fields...that they all come in same row but other column

Comment: no my problem is not solved yet

Comment: @hashirkhan You might want to try a bit yourself, you have got how to do your work. You might want to add another column         `dataGridView1.Columns.Add("newCol", "newCol");` and add remain values to it.